# Finding the duplicated file names in a folder and move them to another folder

Tags: python-3.x, filenames, glob, hashlib

I have a folder has 1000 jpg files with some repeated files and the repeated files with the same name + (2) as follow:

```
21_201739 (2).jpg
21_201739.jpg 
21_201781.jpg
and so on...
```

I need to find all repeated filenames, cut and move them to another folder. For example, I need to cut

```
21_201739.jpg & 21_201739 (2).jpg
```

and move them to another folder

according to my little knowledge, I used the following script

```
import glob
import hashlib
import os

uniq = set()
for fname in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
with open(fname,"rb") as f:
    sig = hashlib.sha256(f.read()).digest() 
    if sig not in uniq:
        uniq.add(sig)
        print(fname)
    else:
        print(fname, " (duplicate)")
```

but the result was Disappointing :

```
21_201739 (2).jpg
21_201739.jpg  (duplicate)
21_201781.jpg  (duplicate)
```

I think I made something wrong or missed something. Please, Can you help me?

Comment: @usr2564301- the problem is to detect the duplicated files name, which in my case 
21_201739 (2).jpg
21_201739 .jpg

not 
21_201739.jpg
21_201781.jpg

Comment: you are right. it's my fault, I thought that the script will read 21_201739 (2).jpg and 21_201739.jpg as a duplicated name. So, it's my problem now: how to search about 21_201739.jpg and 21_201739.jpg (2) and move them to another folder??